# Series Solution of Second Order Linear Equation, IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Consider the initial value problem

$$y' = \sqrt{1-y^2}$$ 
$$y(0) = 0$$

Look for a solution of the IVP in the form of power series about x=0.

I have started with assuming that  $ y = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} {a_nx^n}$. Then $ y' =\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{n a_n x^{n-1}}$ .

$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{(n+1) a_{n+1} x^n } = \sqrt{1 - (\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{a_nx^n})^2 }$

I got stuck there, because I don't understand how to take power of summation.

Need some help, thanks.

Comment: Does the problem state that you must answer in terms of a power series? This problem seems to be much more tractable if you just ignore that.

Comment: Yes, the problem exactly asks me to "look for a solution of IVP in the form of power series".

Comment: how about solving the problem by separating the variables and expanding the final answer in terms of power series??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this works, I wanted to leave it as a comment but it is too long.

1. We have

   $$ \left(\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{(n+1) a_{n+1} x^n }\right)^2 = 1 - (\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{a_nx^n})^2 $$
2. Pick pencil and paper.
3. Treat the sums as "finite".
4. Ask yourself: what is the coefficient of $x^0$ in the left-hand side and in the right-had side? They must be equal.
5. Ask yourself: what is the coefficient of $x^1$ in the left-hand side and in the right-had side? They must be equal.
6. And so on...
7. Hopefully you will get some pattern because as we move to higher powers, it becomes too tiresome to collect at the the coefficients of power $x^n$.
8. By Yiorgos S. Smyrlis's answer the solution is $\sin (x)$. This give you additional hints. Using the above, you want to show $a_n=0$ for even $n$ and $a_n=\dfrac{(-1)^{(n-1)/2}}{n!}$ for odd $n$.

Answer (score 1):

The unique solution of this IVP is $\sin t$, $t\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, and I doubt that it can be obtained by series expansion.

Note though, that left of $-\pi/2$ and right of $\pi/2$ uniqueness is violated!